# Different stream of pseudorandom numbers

Tags: random

I have a homework problem on running a simulation where I generate 100 random numbers and perform a calculation on each outcome. The next question asks me to repeat the previous question but with a different stream of pseudorandom numbers. The side note tells me to to perform two computations within one call  to the program because changing the seed/state arbitrary can lead to overlapping streams.

Can someone explain to me what this means? Why do I have to do it through 1 loop?
Why can't I just call the same code twice using a different seed each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-random number generators (PRNGs) work by iterating through a deterministic set of calculations on some internal information known as the generator's *state*, and then handing you back a value which is based on the state.  There's a finite amount of state information that determines what the next state, and thus the next outcome, will be.  Since it's finite, eventually the generator will revisit a state that it used before, and from that point forward all values will be exact duplicates of the sequence you've already seen.  The PRNG is said to have cycled.  "Seeding" a random number generator sets the starting point for the state, so it effectively corresponds to choosing an entry point to the cycle.

If a human intervenes by changing the seed arbitrarily, there's a chance that they will prematurely put the state back to where some portion of the output sequence repeat gets repeated.  This is referred to as overlapping streams.  The solution is to seed your PRNG once, and then don't mess with it so it can achieve its full cycle.

In your case it means that the values and ordering of your first set of 100 numbers will be distinct from your the values and ordering of your second set of 100.

Comment: How long is this cycle? Is it true that .setSeed(n), where n is a natural number, will always be different for different values of n?

Comment: The cycle and specifics of seeding depend 100% on the PRNG.  For lots of [linear congruential generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), the cycle is about 2^31.  For Java's builtin `Random`, it's about 2^48.  For [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), it's 2^19937 - 1.